# Ruby. method_missing + send fails for mixed arguments with named arguments

Tags: ruby

I have this simple ruby code. It is the implementation of "proxy pattern". It fails on the last line

```rb
class ExecuteProxy
    def initialize(controller_object)
      @controller_object = controller_object
    end

    def method_missing(method, *args)
      args.empty? ? @controller_object.send(method) : @controller_object.send(method, *args)
      return
    end
end

class MyClass
    def no_arghuments
        puts "no_arghuments"
    end
    def one_argument(arg1)
        puts "one_argument #{arg1}"
    end
    def one_argument_and_named(arg1, count:1)
        puts "one_argument #{arg1} and count #{count}"
    end
end

obj = MyClass.new
proxy = ExecuteProxy.new(obj)

proxy.no_arghuments
proxy.one_argument("test")
proxy.one_argument_and_named("test2")
proxy.one_argument_and_named("test2", count:2)
```

Output

```
no_arghuments
one_argument test
one_argument test2 and count 1
test1.rb:20:in `one_argument_and_named': wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
    from test1.rb:8:in `method_missing'
    from test1.rb:31:in `<main>'
```

How can this be solved? How can i pass execution to different class using send if a method has normal arguments + named arguments?

Update. There is working code, answers helped, thanks.

```rb
class ExecuteProxy
    def initialize(controller_object)
      @controller_object = controller_object
    end

    def method_missing(method, *args, **kw)
      @controller_object.send(method, *args, **kw)
      return
    end
end

class MyClass
    def no_arghuments
        puts "no_arghuments"
    end
    def one_argument(arg1)
        puts "one_argument #{arg1}"
    end
    def one_argument_and_named(arg1, count:1)
        puts "one_argument #{arg1} and count #{count}"
    end
    def only_named(count:, str:"")
        puts "only_named count #{count}, str: #{str}"
    end
    def manyarguments_and_named_args(arg1, arg2, arg3 = "def", count:1, some_other:"d")
        puts "manyarguments_and_named_args #{arg1}, #{arg2}, #{arg3} and count #{count}, some_other #{some_other}"
    end
end

obj = MyClass.new
proxy = ExecuteProxy.new(obj)

proxy.no_arghuments
proxy.one_argument("test")
proxy.one_argument_and_named("test2")
proxy.one_argument_and_named("test2", count:2)
proxy.only_named(count:3)
proxy.only_named(count:3,str:"string")
proxy.manyarguments_and_named_args("a1","a2")
proxy.manyarguments_and_named_args("a1","a2", "s3")
proxy.manyarguments_and_named_args("a1","a2", count:4)
proxy.manyarguments_and_named_args("a1","a2", count:4, some_other:nil)
```

output

```
no_arghuments
one_argument test
one_argument test2 and count 1
one_argument test2 and count 2
only_named count 3, str: 
only_named count 3, str: string
manyarguments_and_named_args a1, a2, def and count 1, some_other d
manyarguments_and_named_args a1, a2, s3 and count 1, some_other d
manyarguments_and_named_args a1, a2, def and count 4, some_other d
manyarguments_and_named_args a1, a2, def and count 4, some_other
```

Comment: Aside from positional and keyword arguments, you might also want to pass along block arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass explicit hash as a last argument, it doesn't count as keyword arguments, you have to double splat them:

```rb
def one_argument_and_named(arg1, count: 1)
  puts "one_argument #{arg1} and count #{count}"
end

one_argument_and_named("test2", count: 2)      # good
one_argument_and_named(*["test2", count: 2])   # bad
one_argument_and_named("test2", {count: 2})    # bad
one_argument_and_named("test2", **{count: 2})  # good
```

You don't have to check if you have arguments, they'll splat away if empty:

```rb
def method_missing(method, *args, **kw)
  @controller_object.send(method, *args, **kw)
end

# depending on your ruby version you could do this
# only if you don't need intermidiate access to args or kw
def method_missing(method, *, **)
  @controller_object.send(method, *, **)
end
# or
def method_missing(method, ...)
  @controller_object.send(method, ...)
end
```